# Compare two worksheets and paste matches and unique values into separate worksheets of the same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone please help me with a bloody macro to compare two worksheets (Sheet1 against Sheet2) containing lots of rows with data and paste unique and duplicate values into Sheet3 and Sheet4??
Below will isolate the unique values in column A which are not in column B and will output the results to column D. For this  to work the data must be side by side in Column A and Column B. However in my case I must keep my data in Sheet 1 Column A and Sheet 2 Column A of the same workbook and also I would like to paste the unique as well as duplicate one's into Sheet 3 Column A and Sheet 4 Column A of the same workbook.

```
Sub Compare1() 'Excel VBA to compare 2 lists.
Dim ar as Variant
Dim var()
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long

ar=Range("a9").CurrentRegion 'Change Input to suit
ReDim var(1 To UBound(ar, 1), 1 To 1)

With Createobject("scripting.dictionary")
.comparemode = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(ar, 1)
.Item(ar(i, 2)) = Empty
Next
For i = 1 To UBound(ar, 1)
If Not .exists(ar(i, 1)) Then
n = n + 1
var(n, 1) = ar(i, 1)
End If
Next
End With
[D9].Resize(n).Value = var 'Change output to suit

End Sub
```

Comment: Your have Excel version has ``Dynamic Array Formulas``?

Comment: @ElioFernandes yes, since I have Office 365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below macro will vlookup between two rows for Duplicate and Unique values, and then copy the unique and duplicated values with the help of Advanced filter

```
 Sub compareData()

    Dim LstRow1B As long
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    
    LstRow1B = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        wb1.Sheets(1).Range("C2:C" & LstRow1B).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],C[-2],1,0)),""Unique"", ""Duplicate"")"
         wb1.Sheets(1).Range("C2:C" & LstRow1B).Copy
         wb1.Sheets(1).Range("C2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    ~~> AdvancedFilterCopy unique values
       Dim rgData, rgCriteria, rgOutput As Range
      
       Set rgData = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
       Set rgCriteria = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("AA1").CurrentRegion
       Set rgOutput = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("F2")
       
       rgData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rgCriteria, rgOutput
       
       '~~> AdvancedFilterCopy duplicate values
       Dim rgData1, rgCriteria1, rgOutput1 As Range
      
       Set rgData1 = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
       Set rgCriteria1 = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("AA4").CurrentRegion
       Set rgOutput1 = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("H2")
       
       rgData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rgCriteria1, rgOutput1    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I not sure if you are going to like this, but it's the way I would do it, because the code is very simple to understand.

**First Way** (not my preferred)

I created 4 sheets, but I'm using the sheet code names in the code.

In this picture (just for explanation), it shows the two list to be compared (table objects) and the unique and duplicate ranges (that you can put in a hidden sheet if you want) that will be copied to the respective sheets.

Unique and Duplicated ranges result from the formula shown in the formula bar. For the duplicates just replace the end of the formula to be **=1** instead of **=0**.

You need to adjust the code when you move table 2 or if you move the unique and Duplicated ranges.

[image]

```
Sub copyValues()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
    
    ' Sheets code names
    Set ws1 = Sheet1: Set ws2 = Sheet2: Set ws3 = Sheet3: Set ws4 = Sheet4
    
    ' Set listobjects
    Dim olTable1 As ListObject: Set olTable1 = ws1.ListObjects("Table1")
    Dim olTable2 As ListObject: Set olTable2 = ws2.ListObjects("Table2")
    
    ' Set source ranges
    Dim srcRngUniq As Range: Set srcRngUniq = ws1.Range(Cells(5, 11), Cells(5, 11).End(xlDown))
    Dim srcRngDupl As Range: Set srcRngDupl = ws1.Range(Cells(5, 13), Cells(5, 13).End(xlDown))
    
    ' Set destinations ranges
    Dim dstRngUniq As Range: Set dstRngUniq = ws3.Range("A1")
    Dim dstRngDupl As Range: Set dstRngDupl = ws4.Range("A1")
    
    ' Copy Unique values
    srcRngUniq.Copy
    dstRngUniq.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    
    ' Copy Duplicates values
    srcRngDupl.Copy
    dstRngDupl.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Sub
```

**Second way** (my preferred)

- The same 4 sheets as above
- Only the two lists to be compared
- Two named ranges with the formulas (avoids the ranges being displayed in a sheet)

[image]

```
Sub copyValues2()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
    
    ' Sheets code names
    Set ws1 = Sheet1: Set ws2 = Sheet2: Set ws3 = Sheet3: Set ws4 = Sheet4
    
    ' Set listobjects
    Dim olTable1 As ListObject: Set olTable1 = ws1.ListObjects("Table1")
    Dim olTable2 As ListObject: Set olTable2 = ws2.ListObjects("Table2")
        
    ' Set destinations ranges
    Dim dstRngUniq As Range: Set dstRngUniq = ws3.Range("A1")
    Dim dstRngDupl As Range: Set dstRngDupl = ws4.Range("A1")
    
    ' Insert named range in cell
    dstRngUniq.Formula2R1C1 = "=Lst_UniqueValues"
    dstRngDupl.Formula2R1C1 = "=Lst_DuplicateValues"
    
    ' Copy Unique values
    Range(dstRngUniq, dstRngUniq.End(xlDown)).Copy
    dstRngUniq.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    
    ' Copy Duplicates values
    Range(dstRngDupl, dstRngDupl.End(xlDown)).Copy
    dstRngDupl.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Elio, however I have over than 500k records in each list and won't go with formulas as they will extremely slow down workbook

Comment: You could have told us about volume before! Did you try the code I posted?

Comment: No I haven't try your code, as I said I could do it with formulas simply applying Vlookup and run the code to add it for all rows but it will take long amount of time to open this workbook each time bcs of formulas, also I cannot have both lists on the same worksheet which I did mention in my comments.

Comment: Just updated the code so it will run ok if you move the second list (Table2) to sheet2. If you don't try you'll never know!

Comment: I am getting - Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range, when debugging 'Set olTable1 = ws1.ListObjects("Table1")'

Comment: I have 19000+ rows in Sheet1 and Sheet2 and having dynamic arrays set as per above already uses 693.3 MB of my computer's memory!!!

Comment: First, the error! The code in procedure ``copyValues2`` works well. You need to look at the code carefully and do the necessary changes according to your sheet names and tables (listobjects). Give me feedback.

Comment: I sorted out why it gave me an error! Bcs I didn't create Table1 and Table2 as tables but named ranges on Sheet1 and Sheet2. Where do you insert formulas for unique and duplicate values?

Comment: The formulas are shown in the picture. They where created in ``Name manager``.

Comment: Creating formulas in Name manager the way they are in the pic gives me an error... Why you add `[Column1]` into formula? Can't it be for example: `=FILTER(Table1,COUNTIF(Table2,Table1)=1)` ?

Comment: The formula needs to be as it is shown. Try it in an excel cell and when ok you can copy and paste to the Name Manager. It works well in small tables but with big tables and it takes too long! Maybe another approach, using a Power Query. For big tables may it could be best using a SQL Server database. I don't know what are your means. Sorry!

Comment: Well I have big tables in both worksheets why do you think it will be faster??

Comment: Dear Elio, from the beginning I told you I have a lot of rows in Table1 and Table2 and running vba to extend formulas will take tooo long! Moreover in your formula you have two steps FILTER&COUNTIF do you know how extremely slow it gets with huge data??

Comment: I work with SQL server databases and I have tables with millions of records and I can do what you are trying to do in just a few seconds. If necessary, then I can connect to it and retrieve only the important information. This way its must faster and my Excel files are much smaller. I hope someone else will help you achieve  what you need.

Comment: no idea how to do this with sql...

Comment: Do you have Power Query? Is yes, take a look at [Compare Tables for Unmatched Records in Excel with Power Query](https://youtu.be/ZkY_nMSTIUM). and try it.